# Duvida simples voltar web view

Tags: android, webview

Estou criando um aplicativo simples no `android studio 3.0`, porém não sei nada de programação e com muito esforço consegui acrescentar o webview e fazer exibir minha página.

Porém quando clico no botão voltar o aplicativo fecha, pesquisei na internet e tentei usar uma linha de comando `webview.cangoback` porém as letras ficam vermelhas e não tenho a mínima ideia de como fazer depois, espero que alguém possa me ajudar.

```
@Override public void onBackPressed() { 
   if (this.webView.canGoBack()) { 
       this.webView.goBack(); 
   } else { 
        this.finish(); 
   } 
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tem o `onKeyDown`

`Class MainActivity:`

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }

    public void teste(View view) {
        Intent i = new Intent(this, Teste.class);
        startActivity(i);
    }
}
```

Você irá chamar o `método` "teste" pelo `botão` na sua `MainActivity`

`Class Teste:`

```
public class Teste extends AppCompatActivity {

    private WebView wv;
    private WebSettings ws;
    private WebViewClient wc;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_teste);

        this.wv = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webViewTeste);
        this.wc = new WebViewClient();
        this.ws = this.wv.getSettings();
        this.ws.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        this.ws.setSupportZoom(true);
        this.ws.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
        this.ws.setDisplayZoomControls(false);
        this.wv.setWebViewClient(wc);
        wv.loadUrl("http://www.seusite.com.br");
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
        if ((keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) && wv != null && wv.canGoBack()) {
            wv.goBack();
            return true;
        }
        return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
    }

}
```

`activity_main.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#e6ee9c"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context="com.susite.app.MainActivity"
    android:weightSum="1">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnEntrar"
        style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Button.Colored"
        android:layout_width="150dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:onClick="teste"
        android:text="entrar" />

</LinearLayout>
```

`activity_teste.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context="com.seusite.app">

    <WebView
        android:id="@+id/webViewTeste"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Usei esse, porém recebi 3 erros, Error:(47, 9) error: class, interface, or enum expected

Comment: Você não copiou e colou tudo não né ? Porque tem que saber o nome da sua classe e alterar o código !

Comment: Eu Colei e alterei os que estavam em vermelho, exemplo a activity estava teste coloquei o meu que é main

Comment: Sim, mas isso é a Class do webview... você tem que chamar ela, não é na principal. Vou colar todo código.

Comment: Ok, vou tentar só um minuto

Comment: Lembrando que seus layouts tem que estar batendo os ID's com a classe TESTE, se não já dá erro ao chamar o webview

Comment: Raoni, não consegui, existe alguma espécie de chat aqui?

Comment: https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/68026/onkeydown

Comment: Você deve ter 20 reputação na The Stack Exchange Network para conversar aqui. Veja as faq .
 Não consigo responder você

Comment: Você tem skype?

Comment: Tenho, passa o seu

Comment: jeancarlosnr@outlook.com

Answer (score 1):

Você terá que sobrescrever algum método do botão de voltar, eu recomendaria o `onBackPressed`, mas também achei essa [resposta](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6077141/how-to-go-back-to-previous-page-if-back-button-is-pressed-in-webview) no SO em inglês que mostra um `override`no `keydown`

Ficaria mais ou menos assim:

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed()
{
    if (webView.canGoBack())
    {
        webView.goBack();
    }
    else
    {
        finish();
    }
}
```

Comment: Resposta contendo somente link não são muito interessantes, poderia colocar um exemplo mínimo de utilização?